# A frequency list of most used Java classes available?

Tags: java, class

I would like to hand a frequency list of the most used Java classes to students in a beginner's programming course, as a handy tool when exploring the Java library on their own. Has someone already compiled such a list, e.g. by mining source code on Github?

Comment: I haven't found a definitive list but there are some good threads out there on the most widely used classes and packages: [Example 1](http://javapapers.com/core-java/top-10-java-classes/) [Example 2](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Important_Java_classes) [Example for Packages](http://www.coderanch.com/t/408994/java/java/Top-frequently-java-packages)

Comment: I see no real purpose to this list.  The most frequently used classes that you care about are already in your code.

Comment: I don't think this would be useful... mostly because "most used" can mean so many things.  Would it be class names that appear the most times verbatim in source code? Variables of class type 'X' that are called the most? Does class inheritance and interface implementation matter? (i.e. when using an ArrayList, you're also using the classes AbstractList, AbstractCollection, Object; and the interfaces     Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable, Collection, List, and RandomAccess.) Do call chains matter? (i.e. you call A.something(), which internally calls methods on B and C, and C uses D, etc.)

Comment: @Makoto When you first start programming, you really have no idea of what is available out there for you to use and browsing the Java library randomly can be very daunting. A frequency list could give you a good overview of classes which is good to always keep in mind, and learn what they actually do.

Comment: I disagree. The Java API is readily available if I really need to know something about a specific class.  Having all of the classes in Java available at my fingertips, as a beginner, would not only confuse me, but also overwhelm me.  In my experience, it's better to introduce needed classes/interfaces/enums/annotations on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @Nate I was thinking of a simple "Is this class mentioned in the source code?" list, ignoring the deeper structure of each class. Because these ones are the ones you actually use, irregardless of their dependencies to other classes.

Comment: It seems to me that you based the closing of the question on the background info of why I need the frequency list, which really isn't a part of the question. Because I really can't understand what's not constructive about asking for a class frequency list based off of source code mining.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [AP Java subset](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/apcourse/ap-computer-science-a/about-the-exam/java-subset) and see what is in it ans what is not.